# Is there any way I can make g++ only emit warnings pertaining to my files?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, warnings

I like to compile my code with -Wall, and sometimes even -pedantic. It's partly a style thing, and partly the fact that it does occasionally emit very, very useful warnings (such as using = rather than ==).

However, the writers of some of my headers are clearly not such sticklers. Compiling with either of the two warning levels yields a tremendous mess of output, completely defeating the purpose of compiling that way in the first place.

So how can I make my compiler ignore those warnings?

Comment: You beat those morons over the head with a bat until they fix all the warnings in the headers, then always use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov You need to use `-Werror` too, that way they cannot compile if there is a warning. That means they should not be sharing code with even one warning...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively to [JS Bangs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205923/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-g-only-emit-warnings-pertaining-to-my-files/3205950#3205950), you can have GCC treat them as [system headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html), which disables *all* warnings (excepting `#warning` directives) for those headers.

If the `-isystem` switch is unhelpful, you can wrap all of the offending headers with simpler headers that contain only the appropriate line:

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

Answer (score 7):

When invoking GCC, using `-isystem` instead of `-I` to give the paths to your problematic headers should silence warnings for those headers.  See the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741816/isystem-for-ms-visual-studio-c-compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate `#pragma` to disable warnings before you include the bad headers, then re-enable the warnings afterwards. [Docs on the GCC pragmas.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they're "your" headers, meaning you can modify them yourself or let the "writers" do it for you. If you want to pursue a warning free life, get those headers fixed :).

Alternatively you can of course use pragma's, but they are anti-style and ugly :)