# How to not show compiler warnign from thirdparty files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, build, compiler-warnings

I am using visual studio 2019 and using CMake I generate files. The issue is I am using many thirdparty codes like Qt,protobuf and Lmx which have lot of warnign which I need to supress or not show while compiling

The code I tried in CmakeList.txt is

```
if ("x${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "xMSVC")
    set(cc_warnings "/W4 /EHsc /Zc:wchar_t- /wd4244 /Zi")
```

Here I am supressing C4244 warning but it suppressing all warning. Both from thirdparty and my own files. My intention is to suppress only library files not my own code.

I tried like

```
set(cc_warnings "/W4 /EHsc /Zc:wchar_t- /wd4244:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty /Zi")
```

But this is throwing error while compiling. Any light in this topic is a great help. I found some solutions like defining `#pragma` and `include_directories(SYSTEM "${LIB_DIR}/Include")` but both not working well on my code.

Comment: For gcc (at least), system includes doesn't generate warnings, so marking 3rd parties as system include should solve your issue for gcc.

Comment: Related to: [-isystem-for-ms-visual-studio-c-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741816/isystem-for-ms-visual-studio-c-compiler).